# Почему тег picture не подстраивается под ширину img 100%,как исправить?

Tags: html, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<picture>
        <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="img/s2-big-img.png" width="100%">
        <source media="(max-width: 768px)" srcset="img/s2-small-img.png" width="100%">
        <img src="img/s2-big-img.png" srcset="img/s2-big-img.png" width="" style="
    width: 100%;
">
      </picture>
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделай тег `picture` блочным элементом, чтобы его размеры подгонялись под контент

```
picture {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```